# Почему в запросе на стороне сервера не принимает вложенный Array?

Tags: javascript, post, angular

Делаю post запрос для добавления записи в базу данных. В заголовках отправляется на сервер:

```
{pollTitle: "новый опрос", pollDescriprion: "для чего-то",…}
date: "19.05.2019"
pollDescriprion: "для чего-то"
pollTitle: "новый опрос"
questions: [{question: "Вы уверены в этом?", selectedMode: "radio",…},…]
0: {question: "Вы уверены в этом?", selectedMode: "radio",…}
question: "Вы уверены в этом?"
selectedMode: "radio"
variants: [{variantName: "да"}, {variantName: "нет"}]
0: {variantName: "да"}
1: {variantName: "нет"}
1: {question: "Может быть, все-таки не уверены?", selectedMode: "radio",…}
question: "Может быть, все-таки не уверены?"
selectedMode: "radio"
variants: [{variantName: "нет"}, {variantName: "конечно"}]
0: {variantName: "нет"}
variantName: "нет"
1: {variantName: "конечно"}
variantName: "конечно"
userId: "f9597165-2254-48ae-a4c2-f12fd4f4d5d1"
```

На сервере получаю:

```
{ pollTitle: 'новый опрос',
  pollDescriprion: 'для чего-то',
  questions: 
   [ { question: 'Вы уверены в этом?',
       selectedMode: 'radio',
       variants: [Array] },
     { question: 'Может быть, все-таки не уверены?',
       selectedMode: 'radio',
       variants: [Array] } ],
  userId: 'f9597165-2254-48ae-a4c2-f12fd4f4d5d1',
  date: '19.05.2019' }
```

То есть вложенный массив с вариантами ответов приходит в виде записи [Array].

Код сервиса для отправки запроса:

```
  public post(url: string = '', data: any = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.getUrl(url), data);
  }
```

Код сервера для получения запроса:

```
let body = ctx.request.body || {}
console.log('получаем - ', body)
```

Подскажите, как правильно получить заголовки с полным объемом информации?

Comment: А если в консоль на сервере вывести body.questions[0].variatns,  тоже покажет пустоту? Потому что мне кажется, что всё приходит, но консоль не очень верно отображает. Либо из постмана респонс глянуть можно.

Comment: точно, консоль неправильно показывает, все приходит)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы не висел открытым этот вопрос: действительно, неправильно показывает консоль! Вся информация приходит в полном объеме